# Set redux state by express backend

Tags: express, redux, state

I am thinking about how to change a redux state by an express backend.
For example:
A user calls an Api-Endpoint on my express backend. The "API CALLED" Counter in the Redux state of my application frontend should increase by one.
Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I helped myself with a workaround for such an issue.

Query another API-Endpoint via application frontend and request the data from the server.

But much nicer would be to let the server send the data automatically to the frontend ...